# Scraping a url ending in .js using python

Tags: javascript, python, url, web-scraping

I am trying get some historical earnings data from a website using python. The url for data ends in .js (which is a javascript link). The problem is if I use urllib.urlopen to read the link, it converts to a string and it's a nightmare to extract the data from that string. I was wondering if there is a module that allows us download the data in a similar to json.

The link that I am trying to scrape is: http://test.optionslam.com/site_media/chart/data/GOOG_data.js

This is how I am trying to do it:

data = urlopen('http://test.optionslam.com/site_media/chart/data/GOOG_data.js').read()

Can someone please suggest a better approach for this?

Comment: Javascript *is* a string - urllib isn't doing any kind of converting for you.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the `var =` parts and the terminating `;` and use a ***JSON*** parser on the rest. I am sure [such a thing exists for python](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/json.html).

something like this:

- get the string as you do
- replace all `var` with `{`
- replace `=` with `:`
- replace `;` with `},`
- remove the very last `,`
- read in as JSON

Answer (score 0):

Following the instruction of luksch:

```
import urllib, json

data = urllib.urlopen('http://test.optionslam.com/site_media/chart/data/GOOG_data.js').read()
data = data.replace("var", "{")
data = data.replace("=", ":")
count = data.count(";") - 1
data = data.replace(";", "},", count).replace(";", "}",) 
dump = json.dumps(data)
json = json.loads(dump)
print json
```